# Can't get folder to inherit permissions on add no matter what I try

Tags: finder, osx-server, permission, macos

This is the Parent Folder:

[image]

This is a folder I just added to the parent folder:

[image]

I've been trying for hours to get the permissions on the New Folder to inherit from it's Parent folder. This is what I did:

```
sudo chmod -Rf +a "group:admin allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" "/Volumes/Mavericks Storage/GioCloud/"
```

This does nothing because when I add new folder after running this, it still does't have "Read & Write" set for the group "admin"(I also want do the same for groups "staff" and "everyone"), what the heck am I missing?

Comment: with which user do you create the new Subfolder? Maybe this helps http://m.dummies.com/how-to/content/acl-permission-inheritance-in-lion-server.html

Comment: is a user inside the a_giocloud group